# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Platform despite JavaFx added as Maven dependency

Tags: java, openjdk, javafx, maven-3

My application is not a JavaFx application but is using some JavaFx librairies (JavaFx Media).

The following code is running fine under Windows. But not Ubuntu:

```
static void initJavaFx() {
    try {
        logger.debug("Checking JavaFx");
        // dummy to test if JavaFx is avaialble
        Platform.runLater(() -> { // <-- THE ONE CAUSING THE ERROR
        });
        synchronized (lock) {
            javafxloaded = true;
        }
        logger.debug("Check JavaFx ok");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.debug("Check JavaFx fail");
        // if exception it means JavaFx is not laoded => loading it and waitng it to be loaded.
        final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        logger.debug("Initializing JavaFx");
        new JFXPanel(); // initializes JavaFX environment
        logger.debug("Initializion JavaFx done");
        latch.countDown();
}
```

The Jre is "OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_282-8u282-b08-0ubuntu1~18.04-b08)" (I'm limited to 1.8 due to some external libraries using the WindowsLaf).

I thought I could solve that by including JavaFx with Maven,

```
<dependency><!-- On force JavaFx car OpenJdk ne le prend plus par défaut-->
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-media</artifactId>
    <version>11</version>
</dependency>
```

But then I got the following error:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: javafx/application/Platform has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 54.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
```

I would like that the users has not (too much) manipulation to start the application.

So my questions are :

- Is manipulation of settings unavoidable on Linux (e.g. JAVA_HOME, ... ) and every Linux users is familiar with that so I don't to worry about it ?
- Is there any way to bundle JavaFx within my .jar, knowing i'm limited to JRE 1.8
- Should I package my app with other stuff like suggested in the following post: [How to ensure that JavaFX is installed (espacially on Ubuntu)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42753315/how-to-ensure-that-javafx-is-installed-espacially-on-ubuntu%20?)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to run JavaFX 11, which is build using Java 11+ (class file version 54.0+, if I recall correctly) with a Java 8 runtime (which only supports class file version 52.0).

You either need to switch to a more recent Java version, I'd recommend the following:

- [AdoptOpenJDK](https://adoptopenjdk.net/) (no bundled JavaFX, Maven dependency required)
- [BellSoft](https://bell-sw.com/) (select Full JDK, then #JavaFX is even part of it, no Maven dependency required)
- [Zulu OpenJDK](https://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu-community/?package=jdk-fx#download-bundles) (also supports bundled JavaFX)

I'd also recommend to use both the latest Java and JavaFX version (16 was just released).

Or you choose a Java 8 distribution with JavaFX bundled within:

- again Bell Soft has [something](https://bell-sw.com/pages/downloads/#/java-8-lts)
- Zulu OpenJDK also has [Java 8 LTS](https://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu-community/?version=java-8-lts&package=jdk-fx#download-bundles) version with and without JavaFX

> Is manipulation of settings unavoidable on Linux (e.g. JAVA_HOME, ... ) and every Linux users is familiar with that so I don't to worry about it ?

It's avoidable:

- With Java 8 you can create an "app" from your code with the `javapackager` utility contained within the JDK. The result is a directory containing the executable and the full runtime required. The users don't need to install anything.
- With Java 14+ you have the `jpackage` tool (the other one was removed and so superseded with this one). That can do basically do the same but in conjunction with the Java 9+ module system.
- With GraalVM 21 (Java11 variant) you can even create a single executable file from your code. No JVM, no runtime, just one (rather large) file - can be cross compiled on Linux, Windows, Mac, Android, iOS.

Links:

- [javapackager in Java 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/tools/javapackager.htm)
- [jpackage in Java 14+](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/specs/man/jpackage.html)
- [GraalVM](https://www.graalvm.org/) and Gluons [Maven plugin for JavaFX builds](https://github.com/gluonhq/client-maven-plugin)

> Is there any way to bundle JavaFx within my .jar, knowing i'm limited to JRE 1.8

Not with JavaFX 11 and later version. But you can still do it with the Java 8 variant  from BellSoft.

But **why** are you limited to Java 8?

> Should I package my app with other stuff like suggested in the following post: How to ensure that JavaFX is installed (espacially on Ubuntu)?

No... I mean, not necessarily. It depends on what **you** want.

**I'd** use a more recent version and use the GraalVM road (which is the hardest, but doable, once you have your build set up and running).

Btw: the `javapackager` or `jpackage` tools are able to create `.deb`s or `.rpm`s.

---

**#edit**: Updated links and descriptions, added Zulu OpenJDK as an option.

Comment: I'm limited to Java8 because I'm using JideSoft libraries which is linked to the WindowsLookAndFeel available on openJDK until 1.8. This is an app made on my free-time that I distribute freely. So I'll investigate the javapackager. If not successful, I'll add that the Bell distribution (or alike) is a requirement for the app to work.

Comment: I've added Zulu OpenJDK as another valid option for your scenario.

Comment: While I still suggest you to somehow migrate to Java  11+ and JavaFX 11+ (preferably 16 at the time of writing), `javapackager` should be pretty easy to use, since no module system is involved. It's nothing more then calling it with a couple of parameters, like you JAR file, other required libraries, type of the result (directory, deb, rpm) and - if you want - information about the application (name, vendor, icon; but also initial size, etc.).

Comment: What should I build for Linux : x64 and/or i586 versions ?

Comment: I think x64 is enough nowadays.